# How to prepare for CS phd as with a bio MS and non-academic CS experience

Tags: phd, application, computer-science, machine-learning

I really want to pursue a phd in CS to delve into machine learning and AI, specifically natural language processing. The catch is I don't have a single accredited CS course and little math on my transcript. Based on my relevant background below, how much, if any, CS or math course work should I take before I apply to ensure I am competitive?

My relevant background:

- I have a MS in plant biology with 3 publications in this field.
- Currently, I am a machine learning engineer focusing mostly on natural language processing and signal processing. Most of the math and programming is self taught (youtube!), but I did attend a competitive 3 month machine learning bootcamp. I will have been in the field for 2 years this fall.
- I will probably be able to get 3 strong recommendation letters from reputable CS/Math sources from my workplace, which is very research heavy.
- I should have be on an ML patent.
- 3.4 GPA, BS and MS in plant bio
- GRE: Verbal 167 (98 percentile), Quant 154 (51% percentile), Writing 4.5 (80 percentile)

Comment: If you want to do AI research, the problem is likely not your lack of CS coursework but your lack of mathematical maturity. If get admitted to grad school this will come back to bite you even if your PhD is on the applied side. Unfortunately there is no fast track to becoming a competent mathematician other than struggling through textbooks on linear algebra, real analysis, probability and statistics, optimization etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is feasible in the US, though it will take you a while to achieve it. For someone with a BS/BA, changing fields to enter a doctoral program is pretty common here, but the expected time to completion is, perhaps, 6 years. You are missing some of the basics, I'd guess and your MS doesn't really help with those pieces. Look at the online course requirements for a BS in CS at a couple of good universities and figure out which major courses you are missing. You will probably need to find a way to cover that knowledge base, though not necessarily with courses and not necessarily before you start a doctoral program.

Courses during the doctoral study will be available to get much of what you need. Comprehensive/qualifying exams may be an issue and will cover much of that base knowledge at an advanced level. Be prepared for that.

There is an outside chance that some of your current contacts can get you an audience with some professor who will go to bat for you and try to shorten the process, but that isn't terribly likely. And some universities are more willing than others to use experience in lieu of formal education.

But look at what you are missing, based on the requirements of good programs be prepared to get that knowledge.

You can, of course, apply to a few programs, hoping that you reach a point where people are willing to talk to you about a path to success. Good letters will help, though these would seem to be from outside academia in your case. You need to make your case. It isn't a typical one, so it needs to be strong in some important areas.

And, in parallel, you could work on some of those missing pieces.